# Habilitar mostrar erro debug visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Bom dia, Uso visual studio 2017 e quando minha aplicação da erro nada acontece, alguem sabe onde vou para habilitar para quando der algum erro, mostre a linha que deu o erro no codigo? Quando estou usando debug e chega na linha do erro simplesmente nao mostra nada pra mim.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação você está usando, NodeJS, C++, C#, Visual Basic?

Comment: estou usando c#

Comment: Resolvido, nao sei onde arruma, porem voltei as configuração padrão e resolveu o problema